# Twitter API Email not getting IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I use these codes to receiver user's email,however the email is not getting from twitter API.my account is verified,i set accurate twitter app settings.my account is verified,i set accurate twitter app settings.

```
- (IBAction)twitterLogin:(id)sender {
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
 (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
     if (session) {
         NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
         NSLog(@"%@", [session userID]);
         NSLog(@"%@", [session userName]);
         NSLog(@"%@", [session authToken]);
         NSLog(@"%@", [session authTokenSecret]);

         TWTRAPIClient *client = [TWTRAPIClient clientWithCurrentUser];
         NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET"
                                                          URL:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"
                                                   parameters:@{@"include_email": @"true", @"skip_status": @"true"}
                                                        error:nil];

         [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

             NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:data
                                   options:0
                                   error:nil];


             NSString * deviceToken = UD_getObj(@"deviceToken");
             NSLog(@"%@",result);
             [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager]GET:DEF_URL(@"user/twitterLogin") parameters:@{@"name":result[@"first_name"],@"surname":@" ",@"gender":@" ",@"twID":result[@"id_str"],@"imageLink":result[@"profile_image_url"],@"email":result[@"email"],@"deviceToken":(deviceToken.length > 0 ? UD_getObj(@"deviceToken") : @" ")} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                 UD_setObj(@"loginData", responseObject);
                 UD_sync();
                 [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]hideLoadingView];
                 [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]loginSuccess];

             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);
                 [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]showMessage:@"Error" :@"An Error Occured Code : 80" :2 :self ];
                 [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate]hideLoadingView];
             }];



         }];

     } else {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

}

RESULT IS

```
2017-03-20 23:08:40.030206 Freger[652:180499] [core] Prepared Request URL: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token
2017-03-20 23:08:40.981167 Freger[652:180499] signed in as Berkzsoy1
2017-03-20 23:08:40.981494 Freger[652:180499] 463092374
2017-03-20 23:08:40.981692 Freger[652:180499] Berkzsoy1
2017-03-20 23:08:40.981889 Freger[652:180499] 463092374-ZqlfFhJLAyowxdtNHyRFLopChO1h0zfp4NpkY171
2017-03-20 23:08:40.982080 Freger[652:180499] ydvwd3E3gvg7FKWxe4ILpKxY3NjSoQhtrxKtRSF6cbVeV
2017-03-20 23:08:41.304113 Freger[652:180499] {
    "contributors_enabled" = 0;
    "created_at" = "Fri Jan 13 18:22:19 +0000 2012";
    "default_profile" = 0;
    "default_profile_image" = 0;
    description = "";
    entities =     {
        description =         {
            urls =             (
            );
        };
    };
    "favourites_count" = 24;
    "follow_request_sent" = 0;
    "followers_count" = 41;
    following = 0;
    "friends_count" = 104;
    "geo_enabled" = 0;
    "has_extended_profile" = 0;
    id = 463092374;
    "id_str" = 463092374;
    "is_translation_enabled" = 0;
    "is_translator" = 0;
    lang = tr;
    "listed_count" = 0;
    location = "";
    name = "Berk \U00d6zsoy";
    notifications = 0;
    "profile_background_color" = ABB8C2;
    "profile_background_image_url" = "http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme12/bg.gif";
    "profile_background_image_url_https" = "https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme12/bg.gif";
    "profile_background_tile" = 0;
    "profile_banner_url" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/463092374/1419816548";
    "profile_image_url" = "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/620996292135665664/XPuYYAEO_normal.jpg";
    "profile_image_url_https" = "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/620996292135665664/XPuYYAEO_normal.jpg";
    "profile_link_color" = DD2E44;
    "profile_sidebar_border_color" = EEEEEE;
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color" = F6F6F6;
    "profile_text_color" = 333333;
    "profile_use_background_image" = 1;
    protected = 0;
    "screen_name" = Berkzsoy1;
    "statuses_count" = 14;
    "time_zone" = "<null>";
    "translator_type" = none;
    url = "<null>";
    "utc_offset" = "<null>";
    verified = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for this endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials)

> The “Request email addresses from users” checkbox is available under
>   the app permissions on apps.twitter.com. Privacy Policy URL and Terms
>   of Service URL fields must be completed in the app settings in order
>   for email address access to function. If enabled, users will be
>   informed via the oauth/authorize dialog that your app can access their
>   email address.

Did you activate this checkbox and fill in the other required fields to get access to the email address?

Comment: i activated however,oauth/authorize dialog not popping up in my app.